# How to view console in SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, debugging, console, sharpdevelop

[image]

How do i write to console while compiling a windows application in SharpDevelop? I'd like to see which random numbers are generated in a certain method for debugging purposes.

Comment: Your code is not executed during compilation, so it can't write anything to the console. Why don't you just print the results at runtime in a Debug build?

Comment: I am used to using eclipse for java development. In eclipse, i can create a JFrame, use buttons etc and write to console. It is very handy 4 debugging. I was looking for a similar function in SharpDevelop

Comment: I don't know anything about Eclipse. Is View -> Debug -> Console not what you're looking for?

Comment: ah! thnx...i'll give that a try :)

Comment: doesn't seem to be working? i put Console.Write("print info"); at a certain point and nothing prints?

Comment: Like I said, your code doesn't run at compilation, it is only executed at runtime. The other reason that might not work is if you don't have a console application. You haven't mentioned which it is. If it's a windowed application, you'll need to use `Debug.Write` instead.

Comment: Ok. When i run my code, i can't write to console. It is a windows application, not a console application, so perhaps that's the issue. I tried Debug.Write("output"); and it doesn't seem to be an available method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to view compiling output, then select "Output" from "View" menu. Output window will appear at bottom of SharpDevelop. Select "Build" from drop-down list.

[image: SharpDevelop Output Menu item and Output Window]

Debug output will appear when "Debug" selected for output.

[image: SharpDevelop debug output]

Console.Output will never appear anywhere inside IDE - SharpDevelop didn't catch this. You can see it only inside console window of your application.

Code from last screenshoot:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Random rd;
        private const int buttonsCount = 42;

        public MainForm()
        {
            rd = new Random();
            Text = "Click on me!";
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            compMode();
        }   

        public void compMode()
        {
            int rn = rd.Next(1, buttonsCount);
            Debug.WriteLine("rn is {0}", rn);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx 4 that. Could u tell me how to write to the output window. Console.Write("output"); doesn't output anything? Debug.Write(); isn't accepted...

Comment: @user3541263 , why it isn't accepted? It totally works(answer updated).

Comment: how do i share an image here?

Comment: i don't have main method. I am developing a windows application and running from the MainForm class without a main method. When i code the Debug.WriteLine statement it doesn't accept it?

Comment: @user3541263, it's don't matter. Try to set breakpoint on this line and start debugging. If there is no output at debug window, then only possible reason is that this code is not been executed at all.

Comment: the code is executed. Why isn't Debug.WriteLine accepted? as u can see it is brown in the image i posted...do i need an import for it?

Comment: @user3541263: The full name is `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: @user3541263 , Added working sample(it's Windows Forms application; function will be executed when you click on form), and updated second screenshot. Try to debug anyway - it's really don't seem that this lines of your code is executed if you have no any debug output.

Comment: but then again, why isn't the Debug.WriteLine accepted? as you can see its colored brown in my image

Comment: @user3541263 , You don't have "using System.Diagnostics;"("Debug" is part of this Namespace) written it current cs-file header. You can add it yourself, or click on "Debug" keyword on this line in SharpDevelop, wait about a second, "pencil icon"(actions smart-button) will apear, click on it and select "using System.Diagnostics;" - SharpDevelop will add this line for you.

Comment: using System.Diagnostics; this was the key. i was missing this in my imports. i actually had this: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine in my imports and it was colored grey. i deleted the last part and now the Debug.WriteLine() is accepted :)

Comment: thnx guys :) ur a great bunch :) thnx for the help...and for putting up with me ;) especially u @rufanov :)